# Angular 2 : I want to fetch chat messages but i got error when i use observable timer

Tags: angular

I want to fetch chat automatically after 1 second from server but i got error when i use observable timer, please suggest me.
 The error that i got in console is below in quotes:-

```
" Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers…} "
```

This is my code that i use in angular 2.0 , in function ngOnInit i am using timer that gave me error after few seconds in console.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from "@angular/http";
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';


import { Chat } from "../chat.interface";
import { ChatService } from '../chat.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat-box',
  templateUrl: './chat-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat-box.component.css'],
  providers: [ChatService]
})

export class ChatBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  thumb="http://www.lovemarks.com/wp-content/uploads/profile-avatars/default-avatar.png";
  data = [];
  messages = [];
  error ='';
  constructor(private chatService: ChatService) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    let timer = Observable.timer(10, 500);
    timer.subscribe(() => this.newMessage());
  }
  bubble(){
    this.chatService.getMessages()
    .subscribe(
      (data) => this.data = this.data,
      (error: Response) => console.log(error)
    );
  }
  newMessage(){
    this.chatService.checkMessages()
        .subscribe(
          (data) => this.messages = this.messages.concat(data.messages),
          (error: Response) => console.log(error)
        );
  }
  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.chatService.createMessage(form.value.message)
      .subscribe(
        () => this.newMessage()
      );
    form.reset();
  }

}
```

Comment: Forgive me, why not use websockets or socket.io?

Comment: websocket in Laravel or in angular 2.0 ? because i am using laravel 5.4 in backend

Comment: I guess my question regards streaming as opposed to constant REST calls.

Comment: sorry to ask but i am new in this thing , can you explain me that on backend i have to use websocket (laravel 5.4 pp) or in angular

Comment: I'm fairly new to it.  It's implementation takes place both at the front and back end; the Kaazing  websockets site offers a sample chat application that will show you the structure of the communication using sockets.  For the front end, you'd need to somehow embed the JavaScript implementation in your angular project.  That's new territory for me.

Comment: Thanks alot May i know your full name please?